# Сохранение переменной значения при обнулении

Tags: python, python-3.x

Что мне делать? Я выполняю вот уже второе задание и во второй раз одна и та же ошибка, не дающая мне получать репутацию. Не понимаю, как решить проблему. Выдержка ошибки ниже.

```
squares(5) should return [1, 4, 9, 16, 25] ( получилось такое: [1, 4, 9, 16, 25]
```

Дальше демонстрация прикола:

```
squares(?)
 Log
Testing for: 18
[1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81, 100, 121, 144, 169, 196, 225, 256, 289, 324]
 should equal [1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81, 100, 121, 144, 169, 196, 225, 256, 289, 324]
```

Ошибка заключается в повторении предыдущих результатов в начале ответа. У меня код прописан в функции, которую и вызывает сайт, там же прописал list_=[], в этот список пишу ответы и оттуда же вывожу. То есть, я по-умолчанию обнуляю список при каждом вызове функции. Я пытался и внутри функции это делать, но не помогло.
Функция ниже:

```
def squares(n,list_=[]):

    for i in range(1,n+1):
        list_.append(i**2)
    return(list_)
```

Comment: Какой сайт? О чём речь?

Comment: @dIm0n , имел в виду codewars

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Значения по умолчанию нельзя ставить изменяемые, иначе можно напороться на тот факт, что они от вызова функции не будут изменяться (ссылаться на тот же список будут).
В вашем случае логично сделать так:

```
def squares(n,list_=None):
    if list_ is None:
        list_ = []
    for i in range(1,n+1):
        list_.append(i**2)
    return(list_)
```

Comment: `if list_ is None:` ?

Comment: Ну, так более читаемо будет, согласен, но данный вариант тоже работает.

Answer (score 2):

Кто вас учит так делать? Зачем вообще в параметрах список?

```
def squares(n):
    list_ = []
    for i in range(1,n+1):
        list_.append(i**2)
    return(list_)
```

Comment: Мне кажется, что в вашем случае человек не может передать собственный параметр :), скорее всего это ожидаемое поведение, но все таки смысл поменялся сильно.

Comment: Я самоучка) Просто решил сделать код чуть более емким и аккуратным

Comment: @LegendaryHunter хотите аккуратности посмотрите в сторону [type hints](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#module-typing) для таких случаев.